# Cannot get rid of following error "pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch" on Lion OSX

Tags: sql, macos, postgresql, osx-lion, pg-dump

I am trying to download the dump of a database on Heroku in the following way:

```
pg_dump dc6psqngs8h580 -h url_address -U user_name> db.sql
```

but I am getting this error all the time:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.2.4; pg_dump version: 9.1.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I found topics with this error here on SO, but none of them helped me out with this issue.
I added:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

into `~/.profile`, also I added

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
```

into `~/.bash_profile`, but none of these helped me to successfully download the dump.

Where can be yet the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: You have pg_dump 9.1.5 which is outdated for your heroku db but it's not clear whether you also have pg_dump 9.2.4 somewhere else (then it makes sense to update the PATH) or if you don't have it at all (then you must install it, changing the PATH can't help).

Answer (score 0):

Install PostgreSQL 9.2.x whether by homebrew, from source, or some other means.

Basically you can dump an older server with a newer version of the dump file, but not the other way around.  This exists to ensure that newer features of the db are not ignored in the dump and there are no command line switches to get around the error.